# How can you limit which users have Docker exec access in a shared environment?

Tags: docker

We are using a Docker orchestration tool to deploy multiple containers to a shared box. We would like to allow users to run commands against their containers using Docker [exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/), but we want to limit their access to only their containers. Is there a way to do this?

For example:

- Bob deploys Docker container Bob1 and Bob2
- Sally deploys Sally1 and Sally2
- Bob can run "docker exec -d Bob1" but NOT "docker exec -d Sally1"

The only solution I've thought of is to edit sudoers to limit the docker exec by the name of the container and then try to limit the orchestration tool so that user's name is appended to the docker container name, but this will be hard to do.